# Invalid XML format after removing node

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I have a form with load, save, add and navigation buttons, which manipulates an XML file.

Here's the structure and content of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BookList>
  <Book>
    <Title>Song of myself</Title>
    <Author>Walt Whitman</Author>
    <isbn>234-0232</isbn>
    <Year>1999</Year>
    <Editure>Some editure</Editure>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>Richard III</Title>
    <Author>William Shakespeare</Author>
    <isbn>234-23432</isbn>
    <Year>2001</Year>
    <Editure>Some other editure</Editure>
  </Book>
</BookList>
```

And here's the code for the delete button (which I have issues with):

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//BookList/Book");  

    foreach (XmlNode item in nodes)
    {                     
        string ISBN = item["isbn"].InnerText;

        if (ISBN == textBox3.Text)
        {
            try
            {
                item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item);                           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }                            
        }                    
    }

    saveFile();

    xpatNav = moveToFirstBook(xpatNav);
    List<String> values = this.retrieveCurrentValues(xpatNav);
    loadTextBoxes(values);                
}
```

The form has an ISBN text field. The code iterates through the XML nodes and, if the ISBN of the current node is the same as the ISBN of the node from the form, it deletes it (well, it should). Then the file is saved, and the form positions itself on the first node (the last three nodes).

However, let's say we position ourselves on the last book - when I press the delete button, all I get is a messed up xml file, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BookList>
  <Book>
    <Title>Song of myself</Title>
    <Author>Walt Whitman</Author>
    <isbn>234-0232</isbn>
    <Year>1999</Year>
    <Editure>Some editure</Editure>
  </Book>
  </BookList>
    <Title>Richard III</Title>
    <Author>William Shakespeare</Author>
    <isbn>234-23432</isbn>
    <Year>2001</Year>
    <Editure>Some other editure</Editure>
  </Book>
</BookList>
```

I tried a multitude of ways to accomplish it, but I simply don't get it.

[EDIT]
Ok, so I changed a bit the code, at the suggestion of Jens Erat. The delete button code looks like(minor change though):

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlNodeList node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ListaCarti/Carte[isbn='" + textBox3.Text + "']");

            try
            {
                node.Item(0).ParentNode.RemoveChild(node.Item(0));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            saveFile();

            xpatNav = moveToFirstBook(xpatNav);
            List<String> values = this.retrieveCurrentValues(xpatNav);
            loadTextBoxes(values);
        }
```

Here's the code for saving the file:

```
private void saveFile()
        {
            fs = new FileStream(this.openedXml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
            xmlDoc.Save(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

where this.openedXml it's the path to the opened XML.

And here's the code for the loading button:

```
public void loadXml()
        {
            if (XMLloaded)
            {                   
                try
                {
                    fs = new FileStream(this.openedXml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    xmlDoc.Load(fs);
                    fs.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                xpatNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

                XPathNavigator xnav = xpatNav;

                countNodes(xnav);

                // we load the first value into the form
                if (this.nodesNumber > 0)  // if the XML it's not empty
                {    
                    xnav = moveToFirstBook(xnav


                    //this retrieve the values for current title, author, isbn, editure
                    List<string> values = retrieveCurrentValues(xnav);                

                    loadTextBoxes(values);
                }
            }
        }
```

I think this looks a bit messy, so here could be a problem.

Comment: Your 2nd example is invalid XML, are you sure this is from an XmlDocument? If so, mak sure to post te Load & Save code. Looks like you do a partial overwrite of the file.

Comment: `SelectNodes` seems to use XPath expressions; if so, you could save the loop and use `//BookList/Book[isbn='234-23432']` (constructed from the ISBN variable, of course. Cannot help you with your issue though.

Comment: seems as if the file is opened for Append, Rewinded and then Written the Stream...

Comment: please post the content of saveFile();

Comment: Why not use LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Save() method. The current one is only overwriting the start of the file but not removing the old (longer) content.

```
    private void saveFile()
    {
      //fs = new FileStream(this.openedXml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
        fs = new FileStream(this.openedXml, FileMode.Create);
        xmlDoc.Save(fs);
        fs.Close();
    }
```